# How to start Neo4j on Azure

Tags: azure, neo4j, azure-vm

I'm running Neo4j v4.x on an Azure VM (Linux Ubunto 16.04). Everything was running fine until my project required a resizing for more storage. This seemingly went well as I proceeded to load data, but then a glitch of unknown type caused the Neo4j server to stop. I could no longer access it from the Neo4j broweser or from python code that queries it. I've restarted the VM. No effect. Even redeployed the VM without effect. From Putty:

```
neo4j status
Neo4j is not running
```

I've tried numerous commands, but this one comes closest to trying to do something:

```
sudo ssh {myusername}@{vm ip} "systemctl restart neo4j V4_0.service"
```

It asked for my password and accepted it (rejected errors) and then gave me

> Failed to restart neo4j.service: Interactive authentication required.
> See system logs and 'systemctl status neo4j.service' for details.
> Failed to restart V4_0.service: Interactive authentication required.
> See system logs and 'systemctl status V4_0.service' for details.

I thought I'd authenicated. In debugging, i tried entering bad username or password and was immediately rejected as expected.

Another set of info generated by the command

```
root@neo4jVM:/etc/init.d# neo4j start
```

result:

> Directories in use:
> home:         /var/lib/neo4j
> config:  /etc/neo4j
> logs:         /var/log/neo4j
> plugins:   /var/lib/neo4 j/plugins
> import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
> data:   /var/lib/neo4j/data
> certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
> run: /var/run/neo4j Starting Neo4j.
> WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed,minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual. Started neo4j (pid> 71995). It is available at http://0.0.0.0:7474/ There may be a shortdelay until the server is ready. See /var/log/neo4j/neo4j.log for current status.

Despite the promising message, it never started and Http://0.0.0.0:7474 did not connect.

for clarification, I tried variations on the one command in Putty: sudo ssh dastumpf@104.43.228.191 "systemctl restart neo4j" sudo ssh dastumpf@104.43.228.191 "systemctl restart neo4j.service" etc.

Exploring the Neo4j log, I found this ....LifecycleManagingDatabaseService@78116659' was successfully initialized, but failed to start.

What am I missing?

Comment: for clarification, I tried variations on the one command in Putty:  sudo ssh dastumpf@104.43.228.191 "systemctl restart neo4j"
sudo ssh dastumpf@104.43.228.191 "systemctl restart neo4j.service"
etc.

Comment: Exploring the Neo4j log, I found this ....LifecycleManagingDatabaseService@78116659' was successfully initialized, but failed to start.

Comment: I suggest asking this either on ServerFault or on the [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com). Unfortunately it's off-topic here, as it's not a programming question. Also, for future reference, you shouldn't add more details as comments; rather, you should edit your question.

Comment: David Makogon.  Thanks for both suggestions. Will do.

Comment: I've posted the solution to this problem at ... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271118/how-to-start-neo4j-on-azure/271469#271469